# auto-increment value on Append CSV function in C#

Tags: c#, csv, append, auto-increment, export-to-csv

I have a function to **add some text in csv file**, i add one line in the loop.

Actually i have a 'int' value who i increment in a **loop**.

But i want to know if is possible to use an **auto-increment** value like in sql ?

Like this :  `csv.AppendLine(/*auto-increment*/+";SomeText");`

---

**My code:**

I create my value with this:

```
private StringBuilder csv ;
private int test;
```

i initialize it before my loop:

```
csv = new StringBuilder();
```

i add my value in my loop

```
csv.AppendLine((value++)+";SomeText");
```

and i save it at the end off my loop

```
File.WriteAllText("Myfile.csv", csv.ToString());
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code, how `csv` been created and used?

Answer (score 0):

One option is, instead of using `StringBuilder` use `List<string>` and add the content.

Magic happens when you writing to the file. Use overloaded selector to pass index, and use this index and format the string.

```
File.WriteAllLines("Myfile.csv", list.Select((x,i) => string.Format("{0};{1}", i,x)));
```